# Json-Server DELETE without CASCADE?

Tags: json-server

I am using json-server for mock REST API in an Angular project.   Works well for everything except DELETE wherein any and all of my json objects that contain more than one ID column are deleted anytime a DELETE request is made.

Let's say I have the following set of objects with related 'accountId' ID columns:

```
"accountfiles": [{
    id: 9001,
    accountId: 1001,
    filename: 'test.docx',
  },  {
    id: 9002,
    accountId: 1002,
    filename: 'test.txt',
  },  {
    id: 9003,
    accountId: 1001,
    filename: 'taxes.pdf',
  },  {
    id: 9004,
    accountId: 1003,
    filename: 'layout.ppt',
  },  {
    id: 9005,
    accountId: 1002,
    filename: 'Spreadsheet 5.xlsx',
  }
)];
```

And these are available at:
`http://localhost:3000/accountfiles`

And I delete this individual object:
`http://localhost:3000/accountfiles/1001`

The entire collection is deleted as well as all other collections that contain multiple ID columns.

Further, if I have an Account class:

```
"account": [
  {
    "id": 1001,
    "isInactive": false,
    "name": "HK Asset Group",
    "accountLogoUrl": "/assets/img/logos/logo2.png",
    "location": "Minneapolis MN 55434"
  }
]
```

And I delete the account id: 1001, the entire accountfiles collection is deleted as well.

I've tried using --no-cascade-delete startup flag to no avail (does not seem to be part of the current json-server build).

Is it not possible to host related data in json-server and do deletes effectively?

Thanks

Comment: Same problem here. Have you sorted it out ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A late answer but better late than never.
The issue is still relevent.
I managed to bypass such a behaviour by redirecting all deletes to a custom middleware.
To be upfront, dealing with complex aspects requires a middleware that could handle all of the compliancies related to your logic.

```js
const SERVER = JSON_SERVER.create();
.
.
.
SERVER.delete('/api/entities/:id', (req, res) => dbUtils.deleteEntities(req, res));
```

and then in your deleteEntities() method just get a reference to your db and manage the records accordingly:

```js
var ROUTER = JSON_SERVER.router('./db/db.json');
.
.
.
var paramID = req.params?.id;
var db = router.db;
var ents = db.get('entitieAs').valueOf(); // gets entitieAs collection

db.set('entitieAs', ents.filter(element=>element.id === paramID)).write(); // replace the target collection by the resulting collection after delete
```